# "Врёт, как сивый мерин"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Есть выражение **"врет, как сивый мерин"**.
Интересно, как оно появилось? И с чего решили, что сивый мерин врет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У сивого мерина репутация подкачала. Он и врать горазд, и глуп, и ленив. А с ним в пару и сивая кобыла бредит :-))
Почему сивый мерин врет? Есть несколько версий происхождения этого фразеологизма.
Первая приближена к земле, так сказать, и основана на том, что сивые, седые, старые мерины использовались только на простых работах, например, на мельницах, а вот работать в поле, и особенно прокладывать первую борозду, им не доверяли. Сивый (старый) мерин обязательно проложит ее криво (соврет) — и вся работа пойдет насмарку. 
Согласно другой версии (более похожей на исторический анекдот), это выражение появилось в 19 веке. В то время служил в русской армии немецкий офицер некто фон Сиверс-Меринг. И не просто служил, а обладал репутацией редкого фантазера и враля, всегда готового развлечь сослуживцев очередной небылицей, шуткой или байкой. Фраза «врет, как Сиверс-Меринг», которая вскоре стала крылатой среди офицеров, была **по-своему услышана** солдатами. А попав в народ, окончательно потеряла свои истоки, превратившись где в «ленив/глуп, как сивый мерин », а где и в «бред сивой кобылы »…
Впрочем, есть и другие версии. Какую из них выбрать - решайте сами.

Comment: Несерьезно. имхо. Про Сиверса. Про борозду - ну еще туда-сюда. Хотя тож натянуто, но, может, есть какая-то более полная версия и там это "врет=свернет" как-то объясняется.

Answer (score 1):

Точной этимологии действительно нет. Напомню, что мерин - кастрированный жеребец, а сивый в одном из значений - седой, т.е. старый.
Но все догадки про недееспособность именно сивого мерина - и тем более немецкого офицера - перечеркиваются двумя соображениями. Во-первых "сивой кобыле" тоже досталось. Во-вторых в народном языке есть масса вариантов действий или качеств несчастного животного. Он не только врёт, он и прёт, он и глуп и даже, пардон, сцыт.  Над последним стоит задуматься, в старости жеребцы - а мерины в особенности - тереяют желание приянять обычную позу мочеиспускания и мочатся себе под ноги почти как кобылы, только с меньшим успехом. Ну а если в вспомнить, что сивым мерином в народе кличут ещё и старика, потерявшего от старости не только репродуктивную способность, но и способность здраво мыслить, то вот вам ещё одна готовая версия. 
(копираты - мои).

Answer (score 1):

Есть версия происхождения выражения, связанная с торговцами лошадьми, в первую очередь - с цыганами. Дело в том, что сивым может быть и молодой конь, которому эта масть присуща "от природы", и очень старый, "поседевший" от лет. На самом деле кони седеют, как и люди, и цвет "конской седины" - именно сивый. Цыгане прекрасно умели на некоторое время придать старому коню вид "молодого": кормили его определённой пищей, чтобы конь выглядел гладким и упитанным, и даже калёным железом выжигали в зубах ямки, как у молодых коней (у старых коней зубы - гладкие, сточенные). То, что конь потом будет испытывать боль при еде и, вероятно, скоро погибнет, дельцов не волновало. Жеребца легко можно было бы проверить на силу и здоровье, просто проведя мимо него кобылу; а мерина так испытать было невозможно. И цыган "втюхивал" древнего конягу не очень разбирающемуся в лошадях человеку как молодого, во много раз дороже его реальной стоимости, утверждая, что конь - сивый с юности. Так что сивый мерин врёт относительно своего возраста - кажется молодым, а на самом деле - старик. Никаких данных, свидетельствующих о том, что сивые кони - глупее или ленивее прочих и что их не любили крестьяне, нет. А выражение "ленив, как сивый мерин" опять же связано со старостью коня: стар, слаб, потому и ленив.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, первоначально в пословице говорилось ***"Прёт как сивый мерин"***, но со временем "прёт" ошибочно превратилось во "врёт".
Дело в том, что при прокладывании борозды (сохой или плугом) лошадь должна слушаться пахаря и идти прямо, не отклоняясь. Чаще всего так и происходит, но "сивый" (то есть седой, а следовательно, старый) мерин уже не может идти прямо и часто отклоняется в сторону, портя борозду — **прёт сам по себе**.

А если все-таки "врёт", то есть другое объяснение: мерин ржет совершенно так же, как и обычный жеребец (но кобыле-то он ни к чему!). Вот почему и получается, что "сивый мерин" — "врёт"...

(Из книги Б. Тимофеева "Правильно ли мы говорим?", Лениздат, 1963, стр. 279.
Подробнее: [Зачем врет сивый мерин?](http://uknigi.ru/frazeologia/vret_kak_sivyj_merin.html)

Comment: Сивый - это не седой. Это масть. Серая, совсем не седая. Да лошади и вообще не теряют окрас к старости. Это чисто людское свойство.

Comment: А словарь говорит, что это было указание на старость:  http://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/1062/%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9A_%D0%A1%D0%98%D0%92%D0%AB%D0%99_%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%9D#sel=14:35,14:59